# Django: logging messages from raised exceptions in REST API

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework for a simple API. I have the following custom exception that subclasses DRF's `APIException`:

```
class BadRequest(APIException):
    status_code = 400
    default_detail = 'Invalid request'
    default_code = 'bad_request'
```

The project uses the following logging setup:

```
LOGGING = {
    'handlers': {
        'log_to_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        # "catch all" logger
        '': {
            'handlers': ['log_to_file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['log_to_file'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

Now if I test the exception handling with this view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def hello_world(request):
    raise BadRequest('test')
```

I correctly get a 400 response with a `{'detail': 'test'}` JSON, but the log file contains only:

```
2019-11-19 [django.request] WARNING: Bad Request: /api/v1/hello [in log.py:228]
```

How can I get it to display the actual exception message (`test`) in the log file? Note that this is the behavior I get when `DEBUG = False`.

Comment: Are you sure the log is from the request that raised the API error? The Django request dispatcher shouldn't get an internal server error from that request as it is handled and returned as a 400 bad request. Also, the dispatcher only logs the request and it's status not response messages. The APIException classes return normal reponse messages

Comment: @Ken4scholars Sorry, I pasted the wrong log message, it logs `WARNING: Bad Request: /api/v1/hello` not `ERROR: Internal Server Error: /api/hello`. Will fix in the description. And yes, it only logs the response code and type of response, but that tells me as an app owner nothing. I'd like to know the actual error that occurred (i.e. `test` in this case).

Comment: Don't confuse the response you return to users with details of the error for debugging purposes. The APIException classes are exactly made to parse errors into responses for the client. If you want a detail of the exception in your logs, you have to manually log them or use existing solutions like sentry etc. But basically, those error messages returned by APIExceptions already mean that the cause of the error is known so there really is no need to send them to logs. You typically only send unexpected errors to logs to help debug later.

Comment: @Ken4scholars True, they are known, but if a function can throw multiple exceptions but with different messages, how do I know which one was caught by just looking at the logs? Logging everything manually seems kind of tedious if the exception already knows what kind of error was caught. I guess I was hoping there would be a simpler solution than duplicating the result between logs and responses.

Comment: You just said do yourself, the messages are different so the response messages will also be different and from there you can find out which one was caught. And if I may ask, which scenario are you looking at when you would like to know which exception was thrown where? Typically you will have the response message the client got which will guide you to debug if need be

Comment: @Ken4scholars I'm saying that a view function can raise different exceptions of the same type, e.g. `BadRequest('wrong author')` and `BadRequest('wrong date')` but in the log it will always appear as `Bad Request: /api/v1/hello`, meaning I won't know if the user hit the wrong author code path or wrong date. And I know I can replicate the error myself, but I'd like to know which ones are being hit by actual users from which I don't have the responses.

Comment: Well, that's not standard practice to log details of well known and handled user errors(because it's already handled and a correct response returned) so it is not implemented out of the box. But if you really wanted to log all the APIExceptions then you could use the custom error handler described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) to log all the errors before returning the response to the dispatcher